# How to get CloudWatchLogs Metric Filter data using AWS SDK Java?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I've configured a Metric Filter to count a information on the LogStream. I can see my results on the AWS CLoudWatch dashboard but I want get these information on the AWS SDK Java. To do it, I'm trying use [CloudWatchLogsClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/cloudwatchlogs/CloudWatchLogsClient.html) class and the function `describeMetricFilters(...)` but the result not retrieve the count data that I need.

This is my dashboard with information that I want:

[image]

In my code I'm trying get information about a Metric Filter, but my goal is get all Metrics Filters' Data, 3 in my case.

**Code**

```
    private CloudWatchLogsClient cloudWatchLogsClient;

    public Object getMetricsFilter() {

    DescribeMetricFiltersResponse describeMetricFiltersResponse = this.cloudWatchLogsClient.describeMetricFilters(builder -> {
        builder.metricNamespace("namespace-name");
        builder.metricName("Metric Filter API-KEY-3");
    });

    return describeMetricFiltersResponse.toString();
}
```

The return don't retrive the correct count, returns it:

```
    DescribeMetricFiltersResponse(MetricFilters=[MetricFilter(FilterName=API-KEY-3 Count, 
    FilterPattern="apiKeyId" "*******", 
    MetricTransformations=[MetricTransformation(MetricName=Metric Filter API-KEY-3, 
    MetricNamespace=namespace-name, MetricValue=1)],
    CreationTime=1574249791147, LogGroupName=group-name)])
```

For the Metric Filter `Metric Filter API-KEY-3`, I hope receive data like: `Count = 7`

Answer (score 0):

Metric filters create metrics.

**DescribeMetricFilters** API gives you the information about the metric filter.

To get the metric data you need to you use **GetMetricData** (recommended) or **GetMetricStatistics** API. You could also use **GetMetricWidgetImage** API to get a bitmap image of the graph.